# MySQL multiple inner join not returning rows

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query which selects from three tables.

```
m_release
---------------------------
 release_id       name     
---------------------------
  1               release1  
  2               release2   
  3               release3 


mk_release_artist
---------------------------
 release_id       artist_id    
---------------------------
  1               134  
  2               135 


mk_release_remix
---------------------------
 release_id       artist_id    
---------------------------
  3               134
```

I've created the following query so far, but it doesn't return any rows:

```
SELECT * FROM m_release A
JOIN mk_release_artist B ON A.release_id = B.release_id AND B.artist_id = 134
JOIN mk_release_remix C ON A.release_id = C.release_id AND C.artist_id = 134
```

It is working when i'm selecting from two tables using one JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM m_release A
JOIN mk_release_artist B ON A.release_id = B.release_id AND B.artist_id = 134
```

The output i'm expecting to see is:

```
---------------------------
 release_id       name     
---------------------------
  1               release1    
  3               release3
```

Comment: Hard to tell without example data and expected output

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there are matching rows in`mk_release_remix`?

Comment: Also, are you sure you know what **INNER** join really does? If not, try to swap that last INNER JOIN for a LEFT JOIN and check the difference.

Comment: @N.B. I tried it but there isn't a difference compared with the example with only one JOIN, and i'm sure there are matching rows in the mk_release_remix table

Comment: @juergend I've added some sample data and expected output to the post

Answer (score 0):

So, in `B`, `author_id` is the author, while in `C`, it's the remixer. Then your query selects entries *where BOTH the author and the remixer are the `id=134`*. Which has no matching entries in your example.

The [juergen d's query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26875394/mysql-multiple-inner-join-not-returning-rows#26875741) would select entries where *either author or the remixer* is the `id`. Since it uses `LEFT JOIN`s, it will even get the releases that have no corresponding entry in either `B` or `C` (the corresponding columns will be `NULL`).

Comment: A is the table with all the releases in my database. B is where the release is connected to an artist if the artist is the original composer. C is connected to an artist if the artist is the remixer. The query is to select all the releases that are connected to the artist

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM m_release A
LEFT JOIN mk_release_artist B ON A.release_id = B.release_id
LEFT JOIN mk_release_remix C ON A.release_id = C.release_id
WHERE 134 in (B.artist_id, C.artist_id)
```

Comment: `-1` for not explaining why to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`, nor why to move `artist_id` condition to different place.